# how to resolve Error Connecting database?

Tags: linux, wordpress

I was getting the below error while browsing to one of my website.

```
Error Connecting database
```

and while restarting MariaDB, i was getting the below error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the path `/usr/lib64` and look for the `libjemalloc*` using below commands:

```
$cd /usr/lib64
$ls | grep libjemalloc
```

if you don't find it, you don't have that package installed in your system

```
$sudo yum whatprovides libjemalloc*
$sudo yum install jemalloc-3.6.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
```